# necesito mostrar una columnas con el tamano y especificar que debe ser un checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

Comparto mi codigo donde debo mostra  desde el ts  el tamano  de la columna  y especificar que debe  ser un checkbox. Estoy  utilizando  la columna  para mostrar  3 datos diferentes.

**HTML**

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Data19">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        {{Data19}}
        <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never" class="table-filter" 
       style="width:80px !important">
          <input matInput [formControl]="Data19Filtro">
        </mat-form-field>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <span style="width:80px"> 
       {{row.Data19}}</span></td>
      </ng-container>
```

**TS**

```
      if (cveTipoMovimiento == 'SA') {
      this.displayedColumns = ['snactions2', 'Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 
      'Data4', 'Data5', 'Data14', 'Data24', 'Data17', 'Data20', 'Data21', 
      'Data6', 'Data7', 'Data8', 'Data9', 'Data10', 'Data11', 'Data12', 
     'Data13',  'Data15', 'Data16',  'Data18', 'Data19',   'Data22', 
     'Data23'];

      this.Data1 = 'Socio'
      this.Data2 = 'Sec'
      this.Data3 = 'Poliza'
      this.Data4 = 'Marca'
      this.Data5 = 'Modelo'
      this.Data6 = 'Auto'
      this.Data7 = 'Transmision'
      this.Data8 = 'Puertas'
      this.Data9 = 'Pasajeros'
      this.Data10 = 'Equipado'
     this.Data11 = 'Clima'
     this.Data12 = 'Motor'
     this.Data13 = 'RFV'
     this.Data14 = 'Serie'
      this.Data15 = 'CveAuto'
     this.Data16 = 'Inciso'
     this.Data17 = 'FechaFin'
     this.Data18 = 'Valor'
     this.Data19 = 'EquipoExtra'
     this.Data20 = 'Cobertura'
     this.Data21 = 'PrimaAnual'
     this.Data22 = 'Vigencia'
     this.Data23 = 'FecBaja'
     this.Data24 = 'FecInicio'
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: @PabloLozano necesito  darle el  tamaño(width ) desde  el TS  por que  estoy  utilizando las  mismas  columna para  mostrar  3  datos   diferentes

Comment: @PabloLozano por ejemplo el campo  que tenga el data19 y tome  uno de  los 3 valores  que  muestra  tenga  un  width  mas  grande  ya  que la  información  que  despliega   no son del mismo tamaño